# Start and stop npm from PHP script

Tags: php, npm, centos7, forever

OK, a silly question. Is it possible to do start npm from a PHP script, via the browser? For example, by doing something like this?

```
// start.php
echo exec('npm run forever');
die();
```

And then, to stop node, like this:

```
// stop.php
echo exec('npm run stopforever');
die();
```

I've tried setting the absolute path in both the php scripts (`/var/www/mysite.com/`) and the package.json, and it didn't work.

If I try to execute the script via terminal (`php -q /var/www/mysite.com/start.php`), it works, but not when I try to execute the script from the browser. I'm guessing it has something to do with rights and privileges, so I might not be going about it the right way.

Is there even a recommended way of doing this? The reason I need this is to be able to start and stop the Node server at will, without logging to the console as a root user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use full path of executive files.

Try like this: (Worked on the Windows Server)

```
shell_exec('C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\pm2.cmd');
```

If you run php by nginx or apache (for example, visit url example.com/index.php), sometime you need to export the PATH

```
exec("export PATH=/usr/local/bin && run forever);
```

Comment: Sorry for this extremely late response. I've tried exporting it through the script `echo exec('......')`, and it's still not working.